# What's the drawback of enabling auth-nocache in OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

Using a "default" configuration, OpenVPN clients show the following warning when connecting to a VPN server in red, attention-seeking letters:

> WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this

Googling for that configuration option yields various Internet sources that claim that this is not really a big deal, but I want to get rid of that warning, because I don't want my VPN users to get in the habit of ignoring warnings written in red.

Obviously, I can do that by adding `auth-nocache` to the configuration file.

**What's the drawback of doing that?** Since this feature is "opt-in", there must be some kind of drawback, or it would be enabled by default. Unfortunately, searching for "auth-nocache" in [the official documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/#documentation) yielded no results.

Answer (score 1):

The authentication credentials are not cached. So if the connection fails, it is not possible to automatically reconnect.